# HighCharts Pie Chart legend Alignment

Tags: javascript, highcharts

basically what i'd like to do is use the data name and value in my legened, but have them spaced so that the data name is aligned left and the data value is aligned to the right like this;

```
Name1           Val1
Name2           Val2
```

etc.  Currently it defaults to be

```
Name1 Val1
Name2 Val2
```

with just a space in between that I set, but if name 1 is 10 characters and name 2 is 8 characters they are staggered like this;

```
Name1isthis Val1
Name2lookslikethis Val2
```

any help is appreciated.  Here is the code and my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/1/

```
$("document").ready(
function(){
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart:{type:'pie'},
        credits:{enabled: false},
        colors:[
            '#5485BC', '#AA8C30', '#5C9384', '#981A37', '#FCB319',     '#86A033', '#614931', '#00526F', '#594266', '#cb6828', '#aaaaab', '#a89375'
            ],
        title:{text: null},
         tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,                 
                cursor: 'pointer',
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false                       
                }                                   
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            labelFormatter: function() {
                return this.name + ' ' + this.y + '%';
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            dataLabels:{

            },
            data: [
                ['Domestic Equity', 38.5],
                ['International Equity', 26.85],
                ['Other', 15.70],
                ['Cash and Equivalents', 10.48],
                ['Fixed Income', 8.48]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: i've tried using embedded tables as well as surrounding the elements with a main <div> containing <span> tags for each piece of data the name and the y value but i can't get them to align anywhere, this is frustrating to say the least with this stuff

Comment: You can use html tags and CSS to achieve that: http://jsfiddle.net/hAnCr/28/ But there are two limits, it won't work for exporting and requires fixed width.